# Extrapolate lowest/highest value from partial sample

Tags: probability

Given a *partial sample* of values from a set (known size), how to extrapolate the lowest/highest value in the *entire set?*

Comment: You need to know (or at least assume) a distribution.  Even then the uncertainty could be substantial especially if your distribution may have long tails. Try reading about the [German tank problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) for a simple example with a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about it would be:

1. Hypothesise a model distribution for your population.  Your population can itself be seen as a sample from a hypothetical infinite population.
2. Using your actual sample, estimate the parameters of your model distribution, and perform diagnostic checks to see if the model remains plausible.
3. Simulate data of the size of your actual population, using the fitted model to simulate the data from the population that you haven't observed, and repeating your actual sample for the part of the population that you *do* have.  Do this say 500-1000 times to create confidence intervals for the maximum and minimum of the population.

Depending on your model, you could replace step 3 with a theory-based calculation of the confidence interval.  How to do that would depend on your model (ie what distribution you are hypothesising) however.  Which would depend on what sort of data you are looking at.

Comment: Peter, did you catch that the question is about a *finite* population of known size and that the sample (apparently) is without replacement?

Comment: @whuber - good point, will have an edit.